DocumentIntelligence join results
This question is for multi-page receipts:
I have a pdf file with two pages of the same receipt. I'm sending to DocumentIntelligenceClient the multipage pdf to AnalyzeDocumentAsync like this:
Operation<AnalyzeResult> operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(
    WaitUntil.Completed,
    "prebuilt-receipt",
    new AnalyzeDocumentContent
    {
        Base64Source = new BinaryData(pdfByteArray)
    },
    queryFields: new List<string> { "abc", "def" },
    features: new List<DocumentAnalysisFeature> { DocumentAnalysisFeature.QueryFields });
AnalyzeResult receipts = operation.Value;

foreach (AnalyzedDocument receipt in receipts.Documents) {...}

The problem is receipts.Documents has two documents each of them with its own Fields. So, basically, I have two different "Total" fields for this single multipage receipt.
Is there any way I can use AnalyzeDocumentAsync to treat all pages from pdf like just one single receipt?
